# Outlook add in (calendar event): Series Id when editing "single event and the following"

Tags: outlook-web-addins, recurrence, event-id

I have an Outlook addin for calendar events (Office 365 Web), which has a taskpane to show info for the user.

I have a problem when I edit a recurrence event, "this event and the following".

These are my steps:

I open an event on day_1, and set a 'daily' recurrence for 3 days [day_1, day_2, day_3].

Then I open my taskpane and I can read the id from Office.context.mailbox.item:

```
  item1_id
```

and the recurrence info:

```
   {"recurrenceProperties":{"interval":1},"recurrenceType":"daily","recurrenceTimeZone":{...},"seriesTime":               
            {"startYear":2020,"startMonth":10,"startDay":27,"endYear":2020,"endMonth":10,"endDay":29,"startTimeMinutes":600,"durationMinutes":30}
   }
```

Then I save the event in the calendar.

**A)** If I open "all the series" to edit I read from the Office.context.mailbox.item:

- seriesId: null
- itemId: seriesId (**=item1_id**, saved value when series created --> I
  know it is my series)

**B)** If I open a single event to edit, I read:

- seriesId: seriesId (**=item1_id**, saved value when series created --> I know it is an event from my series)
- itemId: itemB

**C)** If I open to edit "day_2 and the following", I read:

- seriesId: null   (it is correct?)
- itemId: itemC    ( I don't know this event is from the series I created...)

**My code:**

```
Office.onReady(info => {
    g_item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

    g_itemId = g_item.itemId;
    if (g_itemId === null || g_itemId == undefined) {
        g_item.saveAsync(function (result) {
            g_itemId = result.value;
            g_item.recurrence.getAsync((asyncResult) => {
                if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    g_recurrence = asyncResult.value;
                    console.log("Recurrence: " + JSON.stringify(g_recurrence));
                    console.log("ITEM ID: " + g_itemId);
                    console.log("SERIES ID: " + g_item.seriesId);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    else
        console.log("**** itemId found: " + g_itemId);
});
```

I hope you can understand my problem...

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: In which platform(PC desktop, Mac, iOS, Office on the web) are you facing this issue?

Comment: I updated the question: I am using for development Office 365 Web

Comment: Any help with this issue?

Comment: Can you please try to use REST apis to get this series ID in the 'and the following' case?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know in which case I am when my taskpane is open

Comment: Besides, to use the REST Api I need a valid app access token, don't I? But I don't have any app registered for my Outlook addin. What (and where) should I register in order to get a token? Or how can I use the REST api with only my addin?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

For using REST API from addin please look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api. You can use getCallbackTokenAsync() API to get the required token.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?